# Windows 7 doesn't autorun Portable Apps Starter on Flash drive

Tags: windows-7, autorun, portable-apps

I'm afraid the answer is "it won't due to new security features", but I'll ask anyway.

I have a USB Flash Drive I run Portable Applications on (who doesn't, right?). I use PStart to start up a nice menu I've been using for a couple years, have my configuration dialed in to something that is productive, so I'm not inclined to just switch to another program.

I have an Autorun.inf in the root of the drive. Its contents:

```
[Autorun]
Open=Applications\pstart\PStart.exe
Action=Start PortableApps
Icon=Applications\PortableAppsMenu\PortableAppsMenu.exe
Label=PortableApps
```

When I insert the device on Windows 7, I get prompted to choose from a variety of autostart things I **don't** want to do:

[image: autorun dialog]

It worked fine on XP and Vista, on inserting the PStart.exe would start up and I have menu.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're correct.

The new security features of Windows 7 will not run autorun programs unless it's on optical media.

See more here: [AutoRun changes in Windows 7](https://msrc-blog.microsoft.com/2009/04/28/autorun-changes-in-windows-7/).

Comment: "...so our customers can benefit..." - People who take security seriously and don't put arbitrary devices in their computers suffer from the inconvenience. I'd like the option to allow specific devices to autorun, even if I have to set it manually the first time :(.

Comment: Heh. I am of the opposite opinion; autorun is the most evil thing ever invented. I suppose having it do nothing _by default_ would have been a better alternative to removing it completely.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I was considering for a previous project and I didn't end up starting it it however my approach would have been to edit the following PowerShell script to run whatever application I wanted, in my case it would be to eject all but specific USB drives.
Basically the script monitors the `Win32_VolumeChangeEvent` table for additions then triggers an application along with some of the event metadata such as drive letter. It could be adapted to run any application or script.

```
function UsbMountWatcher {
     $alarm = New-Object System.Management.EventQuery
     $alarm.QueryString = "SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2"
     New-Object System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher $alarm
}
$pathtompcmdrun = $env:PROGRAMFILES + "\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe"
$watcher = UsbMountWatcher
while ($true) {
     $event = $watcher.WaitForNextEvent()
     $driveletter = $event.Properties["DriveName"].Value.ToString() + "\"
     &$pathtompcmdrun "-Scan" "-File" $driveletter "-DisableRemediation"
     Write-Output $LASTEXITCODE
}
$watcher.Stop()
```

Source: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Custom-scan-a-USB-drive-17b9be2a

Further reading: https://alitarhini.wordpress.com/2010/11/05/listen-for-removable-device-events/

This should also address the merged but different Windows 10 question: [how to automatically run a batch file when USB drive inserted in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1467559/how-to-automatically-run-a-batch-file-when-usb-drive-inserted-in-windows-10?noredirect=1&lq=1)