# Detect USB device connection (any device, not only storage)

Tags: windows, usb, security, windows-server-2012

My question is: in Windows Server 2012, is it possible to launch an event when a device is connected to a USB port? I mean: **any** device, including a keyboard or a mouse, not just storage USB drives.

The idea behind this question is as follows: I want my Windows Server 2012 machine to shut down (ergo: encrypt the disk) immediately after a device is connected to the USB port. This is intended as an additional layer of protection from data theft. Shutting the server down is a trivial matter of executing `shutdown /s /t 0` but I first need a trigger for that.

I have done some research (here, on Serverfault and IT Security, as well) and seen some interesting answers, including [this one in particular](https://superuser.com/a/93751/277762). Close, but still no cigar, as the questions and answers found refer almost exclusively to storage devices and mine has a way wider scope.

It might be a PowerShell script running in the background or a trigger in Task Scheduler, just point me in the right direction - I'm pretty much new to the Windows ecosystem. Is it possible to achieve such a thing?

Comment: They can just grab the ram and extract the headers and decrypt your drives? Sure, not that sneaky, but it may work. Maybe you could try applying some "hardware mod" as in make the case closed down tight. Make it impossible for anyone to access the machine unless they power it down.

Comment: Why not disable the USB ports in the server's BIOS?

Comment: Also check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620144/detecting-usb-drive-insertion-and-removal-using-windows-service-and-c-sharp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078909/detecting-usb-insertion-removal-events-in-windows-using-c, etc.

Comment: It's a great denial of service attack against yourself! What happens when the machine is powered on?

Comment: @techie007 Disabling ports in the BIOS is not really in question, because I'm going to use Bitlocker with encryption keys stored on a USB drive, so that I can quickly put the server back up and running if need be.

Comment: @pjc50 What do you mean by DoS against myself? Or was this a comment to disabling USB ports in BIOS? Actually there's a follow up to my original question. If I figure out how to detect a device connection I could elaborate on that to include a simple check: if the device in question is a pendrive with a specific file (or a key or whatever), then (and only then) the shutdown procedure is halted so I *can* plug in a keyboard and a mouse if I need to resort to physical access instead of RDP.

Comment: McAfee Endpoint Encryption can log all USB activity I believe...

Comment: I meant that you've provided an extra way to shut the machine down by anyone who can get close to it. A better way of achieving this sort of physical security would be to put it in a locked cabinet. There's also no guarantee that you can do an orderly shutdown before whatever attack is on the stick is carried out.

Comment: @pjc50 You do have a point here. A locked cabinet, however, does not protect your data from being read, it merely hinders the attacker. My assumption contained in the question is that all physical barriers have been brought down and the attacker has physical access to the server. I focus on protecting the data as well as possible at this very level.